# XSL: xpath not returning the right value

Tags: xslt, abap

I am parsing an XSL file with XSL. And I have a problem dynamically finding nodes in it. Here is the scenario:

```
<linkbase xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xsd">
    <labelLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/link" 
                xlink:type="extended">
        <loc xlink:type="locator" 
                    xlink:href="de-gaap-ci-2010-12-16.xsd#de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other" 
                    xlink:label="de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other"/>

        <!-- many <loc... elements -->

        <labelArc xlink:from="de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other"
                xlink:to="label_de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other" 
                priority="1" 
                xlink:arcrole="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/arcrole/concept-label"
                xlink:type="arc"/>

        <!-- many <labelArc... elements -->

     </labelLink>
</linkbase>
```

I am parsing the `labelArc` elements and want to include the information from the `loc` elements. This is done with SAP/ABAP...

My XSL code looks as follows:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:lb="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <xsl:template match="lb:labelArc">
        <xsl:variable name="arc_to" select="@xlink:to"/>

      <TY_T_LABELARC>
        <LOC>  <xsl:value-of select="//lb:loc[@xlink:label='$arc_to']/@xlink:href"/> </LOC>
        <FROM> <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:from"/> </FROM>
        <TO>   <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:to"/> </TO>
        <!-- Other values follow -->
      </TY_T_LABELARC>

    </xsl:template>
```

I expect this result:

```
<TY_T_LABELARC>
   <LOC>de-gaap-ci-2010-12-16.xsd#de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other</LOC>
   <FROM>de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other</FROM>
   <TO>label_de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other</TO>
</TY_T_LABELARC>
```

My problem is that it's all okay except the element `LOC` which has an empty value (`<LOC/>`).

It means this xpath expression returns an empty value:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//lb:loc[@label='$arc_to']/@href"/>
```

The goal of this statement is to get the attribute `href` from the element `loc`. I can find the corresponding `loc` tag with the value of `@to` of each `labelArc` tag.

I tried it both with the leading namespace "xlink:" on each attribute and without it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are two issues with your code:**

**Firstly**:

```
    <xsl:variable name="arc_to"       
       select="@xlink:to"/>
```

Do notice that the value of the attribute `xlink:to` of the element `labelArc` starts with the string `"label_"` -- and the `xlink:label` attribute of `loc` doesn't start with this string.

So you should write:

```
    <xsl:variable name="arc_to"
      select="substring-after(@xlink:to, 'label_')"/>
```

**Secondly**:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="//lb:loc[@xlink:label='$arc_to']/@xlink:href"/>
```

this compares `@xlink:label` to the **string** `"$arc_to"`  -- not to the variable `$arc_to`.

So you should write:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="//lb:loc[@xlink:label= $arc_to]/@xlink:href"/>
```

**The corrected code**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:lb="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  exclude-result-prefixes="lb xlink">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="lb:labelArc">
    <xsl:variable name="arc_to"
      select="substring-after(@xlink:to, 'label_')"/>

  <TY_T_LABELARC>
    <LOC>  <xsl:value-of select="//lb:loc[@xlink:label= $arc_to]/@xlink:href"/> </LOC>
    <FROM> <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:from"/> </FROM>
    <TO>   <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:to"/> </TO>
    <!-- Other values follow -->
  </TY_T_LABELARC>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<linkbase
  xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xsd">
  <labelLink xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
             xlink:role="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/role/link"
             xlink:type="extended">
    <loc xlink:type="locator"
         xlink:href="de-gaap-ci-2010-12-16.xsd#de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other"
         xlink:label="de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other"/>

            <!-- many <loc... elements -->

   <labelArc priority="1" xlink:type="arc"
     xlink:from="de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other"
     xlink:to="label_de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other"
     xlink:arcrole="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/arcrole/concept-label" />

            <!-- many <labelArc... elements -->

 </labelLink>
</linkbase>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<TY_T_LABELARC>
   <LOC>de-gaap-ci-2010-12-16.xsd#de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other</LOC>
   <FROM>de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other</FROM>
   <TO>label_de-gaap-ci_bs.ass.fixAss.fin.otherLoans.other</TO>
</TY_T_LABELARC>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake with the missing "label_"! You implicitly solved another problem of mine which I haven't recognised before :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//lb:loc[@label=$arc_to]/@href"/>
```

If you write

```
<xsl:value-of select="//lb:loc[@label='$arc_to']/@href"/>
```

then you tell the XSL processor to match the against the string '$arc_to' rather than the value of the arc_to variable.